# Is there any way to use a bot inside a viber channel?

Tags: viber, viber-bot, viber-api

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to add a bot inside a viber channel which will then be use to send welcome messages and etc..

I have been reading their documentations but however I haven't been able to figure out how to send messages in a [viber](https://developers.viber.com/docs/all/) channel using a bot.